# Cannot Create instance of the Abstract Class or Interface 'system.xml.XmlWriter'

Tags: c#

Guys i am Having trouble with Advance OOP and design patterns also in Xmlserialization
this would be my code:

```
    public void Send(Message message, string recipient)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlNode));
        XmlWriter writer = new XmlWriter(Messenger.outbox + message.Recipient);
        ser.Serialize(writer, message);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I also have interfaces and Classes, but it is to long i cannot post it

Comment: I really don't understand what do you mean, sorry

Comment: are you getting any error , if yes then share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class, you are looking for [`XmlWriter.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcsse48t(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> Creates a new `XmlWriter` instance using the specified filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly create a `new XmlWriter`, instead you use the `XmlWriter` static class to create a writer instance.

Given a class `Message`:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Outbox { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

You could serialize it like this:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
    {
        ser.Serialize(writer, new Message() { Outbox = "onething", Recipient = "another thing" });
        var xml = sww.ToString();
    }
}
```